# Indy 10.6 FTPServer won't transfer data with Passive WAN clients

Tags: ftp, server, client, indy

I've spent countless hours trying to resolve this problem.  I've found sample code for setting up FTP servers using Indy components (then fixed them for Indy 10.6), yet whenever I try to connect from any client (Filezilla, my own, ftptest.net, whatever) by using the internet to go to the specific IP of the host system, it will log in then fail with the following (courtesy of ftptest.net):

```
Status: Resolving address of 64.113.100.88
Status: Connecting to 64.113.100.88
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...
Reply: 220 Indy FTP Server ready.
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of 64.113.100.23
Reply: 200 Noted.
Command: USER fk30ftp@skutchelectronics.com
Reply: 331 User name okay, need password.
Command: PASS ************
Reply: 230 User logged in, proceed.
Command: SYST
Reply: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Command: FEAT
Reply: 211-Extensions supported:
Reply: COMB target;source_list
Reply: EPRT
Reply: EPSV
Reply: LIST -laT
Reply: MDTM
Reply: MDTM YYYYMMDDHHMMSS filename
Reply: MFCT
Reply: MFF Create;Modify;Windows.lastaccesstime;Win32.ea;
Reply: MFMT
Reply: MLSD
Reply: MLST size*;Type*;Create*;Modify*;Windows.lastaccesstime*;Win32.ea*
Reply: OPTS MLST;UTF8
Reply: REST STREAM
Reply: SITE ZONE;ATTRIB;UTIME
Reply: SIZE
Reply: SPSV
Reply: STAT -laT
Reply: TVFS
Reply: UTF8
Reply: XCRC "filename" SP EP
Reply: XMD5 "filename" SP EP
Reply: XSHA1 "filename" SP EP
Reply: RFC 959 2389 2577 3659
Reply: 211 End of extentions.
Command: PWD
Reply: 257 "/" is working directory.
Status: Current path is /
Command: TYPE I
Reply: 200 Type set to I.
Command: PASV
Error: Could not read from socket: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm able to work through TCPServer/Client connections on the same system without any problems and I've tried going through 2 different make/model routers, setting them up to pass the FTP port connection to the IP of my host computer.

I've seen a lot of posts where people are struggling with this problem, where some have switched their Client apps to Active mode to resolve it; but I need the Clients to be in Passive mode for my purposes.

Comment: Have you done any debugging on the server side? Do you have the `PASVBoundPortMin` and `PASVBoundPortMax` properties configured with non-zero values? Is your router configured to forward to those ports? `PASV` opens a new listening socket on the server, are you getting `OnPASVBeforeBind` and `OnPASVReply` events fired? What about `OnException` and `OnDisconnect` events? Your log suggests maybe `TIdFTPServer` is crashing and closing the client connection while processing a `PASV` command before a reply can be sent back to the client. Do you have the same problem with a local client?

Comment: The PASVBoundPort values are both 0, none of the examples show anything different and I, like a lot of others, don't know anything about them, sorry.  The router is set to forward all FTP inquiries of port 21 to my server's IP.  Unfortunately again I have no information about PASV, reeeaaallllyyyy new to setting up an FTP server with limited examples. My connect/userlogin/disconnect all fire without issue, then I get the following in the OnException:   Socket Error # 10053 Software caused connection abort.  I get the same result from a local client.

Comment: Btw, I've looked all over the indyproject website and can't find any working link to contact them about the multitude of bugs in the website itself, such as the link to the Indy In Depth book; would really help if they could get that fixed ;)

Comment: if you don't set a range of ports via the `PASVBoundPort(Min/Max)` properties, passive transfers will use the single `DataPort` port instead, and that may cause problems for simultaneous transfers. You really need to open up a range so multiple passive transfers can run in parallel.

Comment: As for Indy's website, if you look at the top menu, there is a "Support" link with multiple contact links. As for the "Indy in Depth" ebook, that is not hosted on Indy's website, that is hosted on AToZed's website, which recently underwent a redesign. [Here is the current link](http://www.atozed.com/indy-in-depth/).

Comment: Great, that PASV suggestion did the trick, I gave it twice the number of data ports as I have connections and now it's able to transfer data; quite a few bugs left, but a great start.